# Как добавить переменную среды к расширению VSCode-Go?

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

В расширении [vscode-go](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/wiki/features#profiling) есть пункт контекстного меню **"Go Test: Profile"**. При первой попытке использования, расширение выкидывает ошибку *Failed to execute dot. Is Graphviz installed?*, с предложением посетить сайт:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Инсталляция [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/) предполагает установку системной переменной **PATH=path/Graphviz/bin**, но можно скачать архив и установить PATH по желанию. Проблема в том, что я не могу понять: куда можно прописать эту переменную?

Пытался установить в *.vscode/settings.json*

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
  "Path": "${env:Path};C:/dev/program/Graphviz/bin"
},
"go.testEnvVars": {
  "Path": "${env:Path};C:/dev/program/Graphviz/bin"
},
// в файл Path="C:/dev/program/Graphviz/bin"
"go.testEnvFile": ".env"
```

... выше ничего не работает, а установка в toolsEnvVars вызывает ошибку расширения *Error loading workspace folders ...*:

```
"go.toolsEnvVars": {
  "Path": "${env:Path};C:/dev/program/Graphviz/bin"
  // и так
  // "Path": "C:/dev/program/Graphviz/bin"
},
```

Как все-таки добавить путь к бинарникам Graphviz исключительно для расширения vscode-go, чтоб не захламлять системные переменные?

**PS**: Установка в системные переменные работает, проблема в настройке рабочей среды для Golang.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить путь к бинарникам Graphviz исключительно для расширения vscode-go, создав файл settings.json внутри папки расширения и добавив туда следующую строку:

```
"go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GO111MODULE": "auto",
    "GOPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "PATH": "${workspaceFolder}/bin:${env:PATH}:/path/to/graphviz/bin"
},
```

Это добавит путь к бинарникам Graphviz только для расширения vscode-go, не затрагивая системные переменные. Не забудьте заменить "/path/to/graphviz/bin" на актуальный путь к бинарникам Graphviz на вашей системе.

Для Windows вам нужно будет использовать двоеточие ";" вместо ":", чтобы разделить пути в системной переменной PATH. Ваш файл settings.json должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
"go.toolsEnvVars": {
    "GO111MODULE": "auto",
    "GOPATH": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "PATH": "${workspaceFolder}/bin;${env:PATH};C:\\path\\to\\graphviz\\bin"
},
```

Comment: Вот этот `PATH` у меня вызывает ошибку на Windows11, о чем говорится в последнем абзаце. Попробовал добавить все строки - результат тот же:(. И мне кажется тут ошибка, разделителем должен быть `;` а не `:`.

Comment: ага. дополнил вопрос

Comment: Так я же написал - _не работает это у меня, вызывает ошибку_.  В вопросе этот же пример в самом конце.

Comment: вы указываете workspaceFolder или env:Path ?

Comment: Это происходит [из-за языкового сервера](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65944416/12915495). Если попробовать его отключить `"go.useLanguageServer": false` ошибка пропадает, но тогда возникает ряд других ошибок, и отключение тоже не вариант.